# Text when hovering in maphighlight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, maphilight

There is a script for highlighting the area maphighlight.js.
In general, everything works, but i need to somehow do it so that when you hover, the text also appears.
Unfortunately, the image is not in svg.
Help, plz, solve the problem!
Thank you very much in advance!
My code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fs8.fex.net/get/044792275349/91630365/19cafc40/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();
    $('#squidheadlink').mouseover(function(e) {
      $('#squidhead').mouseover();
    }).mouseout(function(e) {
      $('#squidhead').mouseout();
    }).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
<div>
  <div class="map">
    <canvas></canvas>
    <img src="images/content/highlight/hotel_highlight2.png" width="1167px" height="580px" class="map maphilighted" usemap="#simple">
  </div>
  <map name="simple">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="216,145,196,178,435,65,642,144,658,111,457,24" alt="Этаж 6" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 6">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="195,195,194,227,437,134,628,196,637,161,438,87" alt="Этаж 5" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 5">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="196,244,196,280,437,203,609,249,624,215,436,159" alt="Этаж 4" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 4">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="196,295,195,331,437,273,598,304,609,266,437,228" alt="Этаж 3" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 3">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="195,345,195,366,438,322,588,345,595,322,435,294" alt="Этаж 2" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 2">
<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="235,403,234,449,446,438,686,450,686,396,449,375" alt="Этаж 1" data-maphilight="{"stroke":false, "fillColor":"6AA8FE","fillOpacity":0.6}" title="Этаж 1">
</map>
</div>
```

jquery.maphilight.js [here](https://fs8.fex.net/get/044792275349/91630365/ceb5d47e/jquery.maphilight.js)